# How to create a TeX variable whose name depends on a parameter

Tags: write, variable, definition

I would like to create multiple `\newwrite` in my document, for instance: one by chapter.

I've tried the following but it doesn't work.

I guess, in the end, my question falls back to: giver a parameter `#1`, how can I create a variable whose name is `\customVariable#1`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{environ}
\RequirePackage{verbatim}

\newenvironment{Exo}{}{}
\newenvironment{Solut}[1]{}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\createWrite}[1]
{
\newwrite \fich@sol#1
\def\nameFile{example.sol}
\AtBeginDocument{ \immediate\openout \fich@sol#1 \nameFile}
\AtEndDocument{ \immediate\closeout \fich@sol#1}
}

\NewEnviron{Sol}[1]
{%
  \immediate\write\fich@sol#1{\string\begin{Solut}{\c@mpteur}}%
  \@bsphack
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \catcode`\^^M\active \catcode`\^^I=12
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
    \immediate\write\fich@sol
      {\the\verbatim@line}}%
  \verbatim@start%
}
{%
    \immediate\write\fich@sol#1{\string\end{Solut}}%
    \immediate\write\fich@sol#1{}
    \@esphack%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\createWrite{test}

\begin{Exo}
This is the exercise.
\end{Exo}

\begin{Sol}{test}
This is the solution.
\end{Sol}

OTHER EXERCISES HERE.

\input{\nameFile}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you should really avoid to create lots of \newwrite, there aren't much available. Use one, and reuse it by closing a file and then opening the next one.

Comment: You might want something like `\expandafter\newwrite\csname fich@sol#1\endcsname` but it looks like all your `\write`s should write on the same file. Plus there are not infinitely many `\write`s. Furthermore you are using `\NewEnviron` wrong: it does not take two arguments. I believe you should explain what you are *really* after...

Comment: @campa @Ulrike Thanks for your advice. I will look for a solution without parameters. What does `csname` stand for?

Comment: there are only 16 write channels in classic tex and some are taken already for aux file etc, (csname == control sequence name)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because seems like being solved in comments?!